# Latitude e6500 Flickering Sreen

Tags: 14.04, laptop, screen, intel-graphics, flicker

I just installed Ubuntu 14.04 on my Dell Latitude e6500 (deleting Windows 7 in the process) and it seems to be running well except every 10 seconds or so the screen becomes very flashy/blurry. This does not seem to effect anything else in any way. 
My system has an integrated Intel® Graphics Media Accelerator 4500MHD chip. Ubuntu seems to recognize it and looking around forums people say driver support is built right into the kernel (I think my system is fully updated). I found an earlier post saying this problem may be fixed by setting the system not to detect RANDR monitor changes:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2188084
but I do not know how to do this. The Menu -> System -> Administration -> Advanced -> Service Manager -> Uncheck "Detect RANDR (monitor) changes" path is not available as far as I can tell. Does anyone know of an alternative path that does the same thing?